# @SqlResultSetMapping @ConstructorResult @ColumnResult doesn't work for java.time.LocalDate

Tags: hibernate, java-8, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1, sqlresultsetmapping

I have a simple entity

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Account.dailyRegistered",
        query = "select date(date_trunc('day', creation_date)) as period, count(1) as metric"
            + "    from account "
            + "group by period "
            + "order by period",
        resultSetMapping = "PeriodMetric.byDay")
})
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "PeriodMetric.byDay",
        classes = {
            @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = PeriodMetric.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "period", type = java.time.LocalDate.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "metric", type = Integer.class)
                }
            )
        }
    )
})
public class Account {...}



public class PeriodMetric {
    private LocalDate period;
    private Integer metric;

    public PeriodMetric(LocalDate period, Integer metric) {
        ...
    }
   ...
}

public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
    @Query(name = "Account.dailyRegistered", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PeriodMetric> findDailyRegistered();
}
```

As you can see I want to use POJO as result for by native named query and use it in Spring data JPA repository.
When I call the repository method I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.extract(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1980)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303136
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
    ... 49 more
```

I spend the whole day to play with configuration nothing helps. Any ideas what I do incorrectly?

BTW,

It should be simple based on an article like this http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/.

I use Spring Data JPA 1.9.5.RELEASE, Hibernate 5.1.0.Final, Hibernate-Jpa-api 2.1.

Jsr310JpaConverters is added to @EntityScan.

After debugging I've noticed that in my case Hibernate uses **org.hibernate.type.SerializableType** with reference to java.time.LocalDate and couldn't deserialize result value to LocalDate, but for other cases Hibernate uses **org.hibernate.type.DateType** with reference to java.time.LocalDate and it works for these cases (e.g. not named native queries).

Comment: e.g. If I replace LocalDate by String everywhere this configuration works.

Answer (score 4):

Use Hibernate type corresponding to java's LocalDate as below :

```
@ColumnResult(name = "period", type = LocalDateType.class),
```

More info: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Comment: I will check it and let you know